# List<ComputableFuture<T>> to ComputableFuture<List<T>>

Tags: kotlin, collections, future

Given a collection of futures for example list>, how can we merge them into one map of futures, without blocking in Kotlin.
I cannot use get or join..

to clarify what I want to do:
List of completable future of T to make into 
computable future that has a list of T.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use something like this:

```kotlin
val futures: List<CompletableFuture<Int>> = (1..10).map { CompletableFuture.supplyAsync { it } }
val results: CompletableFuture<List<Int>> = CompletableFuture.allOf(*futures.toTypedArray())
    .thenApply { futures.map { it.join() } }
```

Comment: but isn't join() a blocking operation?

Comment: @Tom This way it's only called after the future has finished (because the future returned by `allOf` has also finished), and there is nothing to wait for.